# Error creating very large sparse matrix from sub-blocks using scipy.sparse.bmat

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, large-data

I am trying to create a matrix using `scipy.sparse.bmat` from smaller `csr` matrices - my function call is here: `sparse.bmat(HList, format='csr')`. The resulting matrix will be a square matrix with ~2.6 billion columns/rows. However, I have the following error when I attempt to construct this matrix:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      [...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 623, in bmat
        return coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=shape).asformat(format)
      [...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 192, in __init__
        self._check()
      [...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 283, in _check
        raise ValueError('negative row index found')
    ValueError: negative row index found
```

The problem appears to occur when the combined matrix is converted into `coo` format. I believe the problem has something to do with indices overflowing, as the indices of the full matrix wouldn't fit in a 32 bit format (2.6 billion > 2^31). I have tested my matrix construction script for a smaller version of this problem, and it worked correctly.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812942/error-converting-large-sparse-matrix-to-coo?newreg=5647733c9a574e73bb899bc3fffad4d4) has a very similar problem to mine, however, the solutions listed there didn't work for my situation. Running the test described there,

```
>>> scipy.sparse.sputils.get_index_dtype((np.array(10**10),))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I can confirm that numpy is using 64-bit indices.

Is there some other part of my program causing overflow? Or is the source of the problem something else entirely?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track, but I don't think I'll try testing something this big on my modest computer.  You might grab the code for `bmat` from the source, and make your own version with some shape and dtype checks, to verify that it's passing the right `shape`, `row`, `col` to `coo_matrix`.

Comment: `get_index_dtype` is run twice, in `bmat` and in `coo._check`.

Comment: You could also verify that this runs: `sparse.coo_matrix((int(3e9),int(2.6e9)),int)`.  I haven't seen anything like this before, so can only make recommendations based on what I see in the code.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the advice, turns out that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csr_matrix, bmat

a = coo_matrix(([1], ([int(1e9)], [int(1e9)])))
blocks = [a.copy() for i in range(200)]
blocks = [blocks for i in range(20)]

arr = bmat(blocks, format='coo')
```

First thing's first - this is definitely reproducible (I'm using a COO array because I don't want to allocate a 1e11 indptr array).

```
ValueError: negative row index found
```

It also doesn't help to convert the `a` array indices from int32 to int64. In fact, it looks like the problem is entirely internal to the [bmat function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L504-L625)

```
# convert everything to COO format
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if blocks[i,j] is not None:
            A = coo_matrix(blocks[i,j])
```

First, it converts all your blocks to COO matrices. If the row and column indices fit in int32s, it will use int32s (and I assume your indices do). Later on it calculates new row values by adding in an offset (based on where the blocks are). Unfortunately, this is where it overflows:

```
for i, j in zip(ii, jj):
    B = blocks[i, j]
    ...
    row[idx] = B.row + row_offsets[i]
    col[idx] = B.col + col_offsets[j]

>>> blocks[2, 0].row
array([1000000000], dtype=int32)

>>> blocks[2, 0].row + 2000000002
array([-1294967294], dtype=int32)
```

Because of that overflow (and because it's in code within bmat that you can't access externally), this is a scipy bug. That said, you can fix it very simply if you copy the scipy bmat function and retype the block index arrays as follows:

```
for i, j in zip(ii, jj):
    B = blocks[i, j]
    ...
    row[idx] = B.row.astype(idx_dtype) + row_offsets[i]
    col[idx] = B.col.astype(idx_dtype) + col_offsets[j]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for figuring this out! I have submitted an issue describing this bug to the developers of scipy so it gets fixed.